# Speeding up `add` / `union` with sets in python by knowing they are already disjoint

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

I'm doing a large computation where the goal is to count the number of distinct tuples. The large computation `C` consists of doing many millions of the same quick computation `C(x)` for different inputs `x`. That computation `C(x)` consists of procedure A and procedure B, each which gives me a set of tuples, `t_a` and `t_b`. I'd like to return the set consisting of both. Usually I would just do `t_a.union(t_b)`, (or `add` the elements of `t_b` one by one as they get computed) which works fine.

But I was wondering if this could be faster. Here's the thing -- `t_a` and `t_b` are disjoint. Is there some alternate "unsafe" `union` (or `add`) method on python sets which doesn't check for duplicates and maybe is slightly faster?

<strike>(My guess is no, since `set`s in python are just ordered lists, and detecting duplicates in an ordered list and adding an element are both `log(n)`. Still I thought I'd ask just in case. Even a slight increase in speed would probably help.)</strike> Edit: Never mind this, but the question still stands.

Comment: What if you add them to a result list and then at the end convert it to a set to remove dupes? Not really sure how you could make sets any faster

Comment: sets in Python are _not_ ordered lists, or even unordered lists, for that matter, and both membership testing and adding an element are amortized O(1).

Comment: Without code I am not sure we can help you much further. That being said, most of what you claim about the properties of sets and arrays is incorrect, so it might pay to look-up these data structures once more to refresh your memory.

Comment: Try `PyPy` which has highly optimized sets and dicts vs cPython. Python 3.6 also has faster dicts (I don't know about sets vs earlier Python3.x) but try that too.

Comment: @DSM If that's true, then @N Chauhan's suggestion wouldn't make a difference, no?

Comment: The best way to perform a combinatorial counting task is rarely to generate all the things you want to count, regardless of how efficiently you generate them.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, I'm aware...that's why I wrote this program to generate small values to get a feel for the problem